# Code review for Laravel multiple files saving and update

Tags: php, laravel

could I ask you to check my code. Everything seems to be working, but I am not convinced that this is the best way to handle multiple files saving and updating. This is the way that I figured out but I am not very experienced, so I am affraid that there might be some safety issue, or more efficient way to handle it.
What I am asking for is just a code review and some feedback.

The contoller looks like that:

```
class DiaryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::has('diaries')->get();

        return view('diary', compact('users'));
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('diaryshow', compact('user'));
    }

    public function create()
    {   
        $users = User::all();
        $lessons = Lesson::all();

        return view('diarycreate', compact('users', 'lessons'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $attributes = $request->validate([
            'description' => 'required|min:2',
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'topic' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
            'lesson_id' => 'nullable',
            'files.*' => 'nullable|mimes:jpg,bmp,png,pdf|file|max:60000'
        ]);


        $diary = new Diary;
        $diary->description = $attributes['description'];
        $diary->user_id = $attributes['user_id'];
        $diary->topic = $attributes['topic'];
        $diary->lesson_id = $attributes['lesson_id'];

        $filePaths = [];

        if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
            foreach ($request->file('files') as $file) {
                $path = $file->store('files');
                $filePaths[] = $path;
            }
        }

        $diary->file_paths = json_encode($filePaths);
        $diary->save();
        return redirect('/diary')->with('success', 'Everything is saved');
    }


    public function edit(Diary $diary)
    {   
        $users = User::all();
        $lessons = Lesson::all();
        return view('diaryedit', compact('diary', 'users', 'lessons'));
    }

    public function update(Diary $diary)
    {
    
        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'description' => 'required|min:2',
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'topic' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
            'lesson_id' => 'nullable',
            'save_files.*' => 'nullable|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\/]+$/|max:255',
            'files.*' => 'nullable|mimes:jpg,bmp,png,pdf|file|max:60000'
        ]);

        
        $diary->description = $attributes['description'];
        $diary->user_id = $attributes['user_id'];
        $diary->topic = $attributes['topic'];
        $diary->lesson_id = $attributes['lesson_id'];

        //dd("1 próg");
        $filePaths=[];
        if(request()->hasFile('files')) {
            foreach (request()->file('files') as $file) {
                $path = $file->store('files');
                $filePaths[] = $path;
            }
        }
        
        if(request()->input('save_files')){
            foreach (request()->input('save_files') as $path){
                $filePaths[] = $path;
            }
        }
        unset($attributes['save_files']);
        unset($attributes['files']);
        
        $attributes['file_paths'] = json_encode($filePaths);
        $diary->update($attributes);

        return redirect()->route('diary')->with('success', 'Position is changed');
    }
```

My blade form for updating the files looks like that (form for saving files is similar):

```
        <form method="POST" action="/diary/{{$diary->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            @method('PATCH')

            <!-- Topic -->
            <div>
                <x-input-label for="topic" :value="__('Topic')" />
                <x-text-input id="topic" class="block mt-1 w-full border-lime-400 focus:ring-lime-400" type="text" name="topic" value="{{old('topic', $diary->topic)}}" required autofocus/>
                <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('topic')" class="mt-2" />
            </div>

            <!-- Description -->
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-input-label for="description" :value="__('Description')" />
  
                <textarea   id="description" 
                            class="block mt-1 w-full border-lime-400 focus:ring-lime-400" 
                            rows="4"
                            type="text"
                            name="description"
                            required>{{old('description', $diary->description)}}</textarea>

                <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('description')" class="mt-2" />
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-input-label for="user_id" :value="__('Student')" />
                <select name="user_id" id="user_id" class="w-full block p-2 border border-lime-400 bg-lime-400 text-white color-white uppercase rounded-md focus:ring-lime-400 dark:focus:ring-lime-600 hover:bg-lime-600">
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        <option value = "{{$user->id}}"   
                            {{$diary->user->id === $user->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
                            {{$user->name}}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('user_id')" class="mt-2" />
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <x-input-label for="lesson_id" :value="__('Lesson')" />
                <select name="lesson_id" id="lesson_id" class="w-full block p-2 border border-lime-400 bg-lime-400 text-white color-white uppercase rounded-md focus:ring-lime-400 dark:focus:ring-lime-600 hover:bg-lime-600">                   
                        <option value=""> </option>
                    @foreach($lessons as $lesson)
                        <option value="{{$lesson->id}}"
                            {{$lesson->id === $diary->lesson_id ? 'selected': ''}}
                        >{{$lesson->lesson_name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
                <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('lesson_id')" class="mt-2" />
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                @if($diary->file_paths)
                <div class="block my-1">
                    <h2>Odznacz jeśli chcesz usunąć plik</h2>
                </div>

                    @foreach(json_decode($diary->file_paths) as $index => $filePath)

                        <div class="block my-1">
                            <x-primary-link >
                                <a  href="{{ asset('storage/' . $filePath)}}" target="_blank">{{basename($filePath)}}</a>
                            </x-primary-link>
                            <input class="m-2 appearance-none focus:ring-lime-400" type="checkbox" name="save_files[]" value="{{ $filePath }}" checked
                                style="background-color: limegreen;">
                            

                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    @foreach($errors->get('save_files.*') as $error)
                        <x-input-error :messages="$error" class="mt-2" />
                    @endforeach

                @endif
            
                <x-input-label for="file" :value="__('file')" />
                <input name="files[]" type="file" class="bg-lime-400 hover:bg-lime-600" :value="old('file', $diary->files)">
                <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('file')" class="mt-2" />
                    
            </div>
        
            <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">


                <x-primary-button class="ml-3">
                    {{ __('Update') }}
                </x-primary-button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Thanks for your help!

It would be great if someone just check my code and gave me some feedback if it is fine. It works, but I dont feel that this is the best possible solution.

Comment: This looks more like a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You can get some very good answers there, if you're a bit patient. Note that, before publishing a question there, the code has to work correctly. You should also describe in _some detail_ what the code does, and the title should be a summary of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly correct, but I noticed a few minor points you might want to consider:

Validation Rules: In your update method, you have the validation rule 'save_files.*' => 'nullable|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9./]+$/|max:255'. It appears you are trying to validate the names of files to be saved. However, if you're using checkboxes to select files for deletion, you might not need this validation. You should only validate input data that is submitted with the form. If save_files is not submitted with the form, you can omit this validation rule.

File Input Field: You have an  element with the name files[] for uploading new files, but it should have the attribute type="file" instead of type="text".

Select Options: In the  elements for "Student" and "Lesson," you have options like {{$diary->user->id === $user->id ? 'selected' : ''}}. This is used to set the selected option based on the value from the database. Make sure that the comparison and logic here are correct and that it achieves the desired behavior.

Styling and Layout: Styling and layout are specific to your application's design. Make sure that the design and layout of the form meet your application's user interface requirements.

File Deletion Handling: Ensure that your file deletion handling logic is implemented correctly. When the form is submitted with checkboxes for files to delete, you should handle the deletion of these files in your update method.

Testing: Before deploying this code to production, thoroughly test it to ensure that all validation, file handling, and form submission work as expected.

Overall, your code appears to be structured properly, and it should work well with your Laravel application. However, it's always a good practice to test your code thoroughly to catch any unexpected issues or errors.